# Hide the WordPress installation subfolder with htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, hide

I've got my WordPress installed in `/apache_installation/dir1/dir2/wp_dir/` and it's accessed through `http://myIp/dir1/dir2/wp_dir/`
I'd like the users to view only the url `http://myIp/dir1/dir2/` but the files continue being served from the `/wp_dir/` subfolder.

I've tried so many choices, all from stackoverflow, and all of them preceded of

```
php_value magic_quotes 0
php_flag magic_quotes off
php_value magic_quotes_gpc 0
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?myIp/dir1/dir2/$
RewriteRule !^wp_dir/ /wp_dir%{REQUEST_URI}  [L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^$ wp_dir/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ wp_dir/$1
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+wp_dir/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (?!^wp_dir/)^(.*)$ /dir1/dir2/wp_dir/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^/wp_dir/(.*)$ http://myIp/dir1/dir2/wp_dir/$1 [L,R=301]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /wp_dir/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?myIp/dir1/dir2$
RewriteRule ^wp_dir/(.*) /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?myIp/dir1/dir2$
RewriteRule !^wp_dir/ wp_dir%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule !^wp_dir/ /dir1/dir2/wp_dir%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^wp_dir/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ wp_dir/$1 [L]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ([^/]+)\.myIp.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/([^/]+)$
RewriteRule .*  http://myIp/dir1/dir2/wp_dir/%2 [L]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+wp_dir/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (?!^wp_dir/)^(.*)$ /dir1/dir2/wp_dir/$1 [L,NC]
```

and followed by

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404page.php
```

Inside wp_dir, there's another htaccess (generated by wordpress) with the code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dir1/dir2/wp_dir/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /dir1/dir2/wp_dir/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I've touched nothing in it.

None of the root htaccess choices work for me, everyone with different errors. Some of them gives a "Not found" error, other displays the core of the wordpress site but with the content of the 404 page.

I'm stuck at this point, as you can see I'm not used to this file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your entire site is in the wordpress folder - what you could maybe do is copy all of the files inside the main folder, and paste them in the root folder - afterward deleting the wordpress folder.